# Hibernate log per HTTP request directly in HTML page

Tags: performance, hibernate, http, logging

I would like to display all the SQL queries executed by Hibernate in order to serve a particular HTTP request.

I want this information directly in the HTML page returned as comments at the bottom. This would be similar to commonly seen

```
<!-- this page took X seconds to generate -->
```

except it would show

```
<!-- this page took X hibernate queries to generate. -->
<!-- Here they are sorted by execution time: -->
<!--   query 1 -->
<!--   query 2 -->
```

To do this, I would need to redirect Hibernate SQL logs for a given thread to a given logger at the start of the request. At the end of the request I would take the contents of that logger and render them into the web page.

I use Spring MVC. Is there a filter that would do this?

This is for an intranet application. I would like to give my users the visibility into my Hibernate inefficiencies, so they are empowered to say "this took 2 seconds to generate because you ran 1000 queries. Fix it!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use custom Hibernate Interceptor implementation to count executed queries per request and Spring's HandlerInterceptor to intercept requests and start the timers/counters.

General idea is the following:

1. Register HandlerInterceptor to intercept all reqeusts
2. Before request starts, store the current time (for timing info) in a ThreadLocal in the HandlerInterceptor
3. Signal the Hibernate Interceptor to start query counting (counters also stored in ThreadLocal since each request runs in its own Thread)
4. Once the request has completed and control is returned to HandlerInterceptor fetch the query count from Hibernate Interceptor and calculate duration of the request processing
5. Log the timing and query counts, add them to model so they can also be displayed on the page if needed.

I have also created a [sample application](https://github.com/knes1/todo) that implements this strategy and written a [blogpost](http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-07-08-counting-queries-per-request-with-hibernate-and-spring.html) about it. It won't display actual queries and execution times (rather, it displays query counts) but it should be easy to modify/adapt it.